# tabularx option in tcolorbox

Tags: tabularx, tcolorbox

I'd like to use the recently introduced (in [version 2.10](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/CHANGES)) `tabularx` key for the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package. The key is documented in the `tcolorbox` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), section 3.6, paragraph `/tcb/tabularx`, page 28.
I have the latest versin of the package (2.20).

I can't seem to reproduce the examples given there nor a simplified one like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={X|X},title=table]
cell A & Cell B\\\hline
cell C & Cell D
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

What I got is an `undefined control sequence` error in `\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={X|X},title=table]` and this output:
[image]

The colorname printed in the left side is the default value of the `colframe` option, i.e., if you add `colframe=red` in the tcolorbox options, the word "red" will be printed out.
Am I hitting a bug or did I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There appears to be a dependency on `colortbl`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx={X|X},title=table]
cell A & Cell B\\\hline
cell C & Cell D
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, that's it. As an additional question, shouldn't the dependency be mentioned in the documention (like for the `tabularx` and `array` packages) or it is something so trivial I should have known even if it was not explicitly mentioned?

Comment: @dcmst I've mailed the tcolorbox author suggesting exactly that:-)

Comment: With version 2.22 the documentation contains the depedency hint :-)